# What is the php settings that controls how a variable is bound in a closure?

Tags: php, functional-programming, closures, bind, php-5.5

the following two pieces work on two separate machines.
Both machines are php5.5.x (not sure what is x).
i.e. one work on one machine only and the other one on both (the one with `use`).
Notice the use of the keyword `**use**` in the second version.
Sadly, I have no command line access to those machines to check php settings.
version one

```
$a = 1;
$b = function(){
   echo $a;
};
$b();
```

version two:

```
$a = 1;
$b = function() use($a){
   echo $a;
};
$b();
```

Comment: Umm..  with that rep I would expect to see which works on 2 machines and which doesn't and what does _work_ and _not work_ mean actually, Also, PHP versions?

Comment: The first version cannot possibly be working, it can only produce *Notice: Undefined variable: a*..

Comment: https://3v4l.org/il0GJ go nuts

Comment: Why do you need command line access to check PHP settings? Use the `phpinfo()` function.

Comment: If your server hasn't turned off `phpinfo()` you can run it and see the output from the browser.

Comment: Also, you don't need shell access to read [PHP settings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php).

Comment: Which setting/extension am I looking for?

Comment: @AbraCadaver as u see lot's of rep don't really mean anything except time spent in SO. Not working is I get `undefined variable $a`

Comment: You're saying that the first example echoes "1" in one of your environments? Not just that you don't get a warning?

Comment: why it wont work with error notices not displayed, are you just talking about the suppression of notices?

Comment: Dont have access to server logs, I might get warnings there. This question is really only to know if there is php setting (php.ini or compile) involved here. Nothing more.

Comment: So the first example does literally echo "1"? You're positive of that? What you're describing isn't documented anywhere, and you're being very sketchy about the details.

Comment: If you can prove that version 1 actually works as-written I'll eat my hat.

Comment: I am wondering, did you resolve the issue? If so, how?

Comment: @Xorifelse I have since upgraded php version and have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your first closure is experiencing a variable scope issue, `$a` does not exist inside the closure. You can fix this by:

1. defining `global $a` inside of the closure.
2. Use the `use` keyword as in your second example.

   - Only available in PHP version `>=` 5.3
3. Use arguments instead

   - `echo (function($a){ echo $a; })("test");`

You should enable error reporting to see why your first closure should not work in the first place

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$a = 1;
$b = function(){
  echo $a; // Notice: Undefined variable: a in /path/to/script.php on line #
};
$b();
```

If both hosts are running PHP 5.5, the output should be the same. It might be that 1 is suppressing the notice messages and the other is not. If that's the case, the ini settings you should be looking for are:

```
error_reporting
display_errors
```

And as shown above, you can simply change those settings at script run-time by using `ini_set()` where `error_reporting(-1)` is a simple shortcut to `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT)`

Comment: I am trying to figure out what php setting is involved, if at all. As I wrote in the example, the one with `use` workd on both machines.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka There is *no* configuration setting only major PHP versioning makes a difference. You're experiencing a variable scope issue. `$a` does not exist in the local scope of the function in the first example.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. BOTH versions work. Just on different machines. Both machines are php 5.5.x (I think one is .9 and one is .21, but can't be sure)